# No implementation found for void org.tensorflow.demo.env.ImageUtils

Tags: android, tensorflow, computer-vision

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID:
             18952 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void 
            org.tensorflow.demo.env.ImageUtils.convertYUV420SPToARGB8888(byte[], int[], int,
             int, boolean) (tried 
            Java_org_tensorflow_demo_env_ImageUtils_convertYUV420SPToARGB8888 and 
        Java_org_tensorflow_demo_env_ImageUtils_convertYUV420SPToARGB8888___3B_3IIIZ) at
         org.tensorflow.demo.env.ImageUtils.convertYUV420SPToARGB8888(Native Method) at
         org.tensorflow.demo.CameraActivity.onPreviewFrame(CameraActivity.java:113) at
         android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1183) at 
        android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at 
        android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at 
        android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) at
         java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at 
        com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

> Here I got this error when I open the Tensorflow demo.It seems like java class did not identify native function.how can I solve that?

Comment: This issue appears to have been caused by conversion functions not being able to use a fallback when native methods are not found, and has been fixed in commit ada51982f60746c2c2147117c5f2e0c972725143

Answer (score 2):

Add **armeabi-v7a** directory (or another name according to your device) to  **jniLibs**.
inside this directory put all files from the native directory https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/

[The directory will be same as this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TWki.png)

Comment: This worked! However in my case the directory name was **libs**, not **jniLibs**